# 良さそう usage in this context:【誰かが手伝ってくれたら、せめて「ありがとう」ぐらいは言ったって良さそうなものだったのに。】

Tags: words, set-phrases

> 誰かが手伝ってくれたら、せめて「ありがとう」ぐらいは言ったって良さそうなものだったのに。
> You might at least have said, "Thank you", when someone helped you.

Source: https://jisho.org/sentences/51866b92d5dda7e98100cf56

In this sentence, what are the subtle differences between「良さそうな(もの)」and「よい（もの）」? Would replacing with「よい（もの）」be grammatically correct and sound natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

（Vしても/したって）[よさそうなものだ](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%88%E3%81%95%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0) is a set expression meaning *could*, implying the speaker's complaint.

Regarding replacement by 良い,  良いものだったのに is grammatical but sounds unnatural. It is possible to use 良い in the form 良いものだが (or 良いだろうに). I don't feel difference in meaning (良さそうなものだったのに vs  良いものだが), but 良さそうなものだったのに sounds gender neutral or possibly feminine and 良いものだが sounds masculine.